com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException: Missing type id while fetching data from redis cache
I have implemented a redis cache in a spring boot project.
Below is the code used to cache the data returned by the method. when executed first time , it stores data into cache successfully.

EDIT

@Cacheable(value = "ProgramCache", key="#programId")
public LoyaltyClass findProgramFromGoogle(String programId) {
    try {
        LoyaltyClass loyaltyClass = AuthenticationService.service.loyaltyclass().get(generateClassId(programId)).execute();
        logger.info("Program fetched {}", programId);
        return loyaltyClass;

    } catch (GoogleJsonResponseException ex) {
        if (ex.getStatusCode() != 404) {
            // Something else went wrong...
            logger.info("Error while fetching program from google  {} ", ex);
            throw new ClientErrorException();
        }
        /* if program is not yet registered at Google's end we get this exception */
        throw new ProgramNotRegisteredException();
    }catch (IOException e) {
        logger.info("Error while fetching class {} \n {} ", e);
        throw new ClientErrorException();
    }
}

But when I executed for the second time , it tries to get data from cache and throws the exception
After doing some research i found somewhere I need to create bean of objectmapper I did that but still getting same error.
 2024-07-05 15:35:06.494 ERROR 23172 --- [nio-8652-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]      : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/googlewallet] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.SerializationException: Could not read JSON: Missing type id when trying to resolve subtype of [simple type, class java.lang.Object]: missing type id property '@class'
at [Source: (byte[])"{}"; line: 1, column: 2]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException: Missing type id when trying to resolve subtype of [simple type, class java.lang.Object]: missing type id property '@class'
 at [Source: (byte[])"{}"; line: 1, column: 2]] with root cause

    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException: Missing type id when trying to resolve subtype of [simple type, class java.lang.Object]: missing type id property '@class'
at [Source: (byte[])"{}"; line: 1, column: 2]
at 
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException.from(InvalidTypeIdException.java:43) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.missingTypeIdException(DeserializationContext.java:1794) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingTypeId(DeserializationContext.java:1323) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.TypeDeserializerBase._handleMissingTypeId(TypeDeserializerBase.java:302) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer._deserializeTypedUsingDefaultImpl(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:166) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromObject(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:107) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromAny(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:195) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.UntypedObjectDeserializer$Vanilla.deserializeWithType(UntypedObjectDeserializer.java:710) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.TypeWrappedDeserializer.deserialize(TypeWrappedDeserializer.java:68) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4526) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3529) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer.deserialize(GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer.java:150) ~[spring-data-redis-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer.deserialize(GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer.java:130) ~[spring-data-redis-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.DefaultRedisElementReader.read(DefaultRedisElementReader.java:49) ~[spring-data-redis-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.RedisSerializationContext$SerializationPair.read(RedisSerializationContext.java:272) ~[spring-data-redis-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
at org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCache.deserializeCacheValue(RedisCache.java:280) ~[spring-data-redis-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
at org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCache.lookup(RedisCache.java:94) ~[spring-data-redis-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
at org.springframework.cache.support.AbstractValueAdaptingCache.get(AbstractValueAdaptingCache.java:58) ~[spring-context-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.AbstractCacheInvoker.doGet(AbstractCacheInvoker.java:73) ~[spring-context-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.findInCaches(CacheAspectSupport.java:571) ~[spring-context-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.findCachedItem(CacheAspectSupport.java:536) ~[spring-context-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:402) ~[spring-context-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:345) ~[spring-context-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:64) ~[spring-context-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750) ~[spring-aop-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:692) ~[spring-aop-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]

RedisConfig.java
@Configuration
public class RedisConfig {

    @Bean
    public RedisCacheManager cacheManager(RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory) {
        RedisSerializer<Object> serializer = new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer(objectMapper());
        RedisCacheConfiguration config = RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig()
                .serializeValuesWith(RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair.fromSerializer(serializer));
        return RedisCacheManager.builder(redisConnectionFactory)
                .cacheDefaults(config)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.activateDefaultTyping(
                BasicPolymorphicTypeValidator.builder()
                        .allowIfBaseType(Object.class)
                        .build(),
                ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL,
                JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY
        );
        return objectMapper;
    }

}


Let's first analyze the error log.
Missing type id when trying to resolve subtype of [simple type, class java.lang.Object]: missing type id property @class
This log indicates that Jackson library failed to find the necessary @Class type ID property when deserializing JSON.
Returning to the issue, we successfully persist data when saving it, but an exception occurs when retrieving data from the cache. This indicates that there's an issue with Jackson library deserializing JSON.

In your case, using the @JsonTypeInfo annotation could potentially be a solution.
@JsonTypeInfo(
    use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS,
    include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
    property = "@class",
    defaultImpl = YourCachedObject.class
)
public class YourCachedObject {
    // methods
}

You can specify a default implementation class to use when the type information cannot be found in the JSON, using the defaultImpl option.
If this method doesn't address the problem, please show me any additional code so I can give a more accurate response. Also, I'd appreciate it if you could show me the serialized JSON string.
have a great day - kevin
Relative Documents

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/2968


the class I am storing in a cache is a library class(not controlled by me).
